# Underscore cursor vanishes when using arrow keys

Tags: windows-vista, command-line, powershell, cursor

In cmd and Powershell on my Vista machine, the underscore cursor blinks regularly. Pressing any key causes it to disappear for a moment, then resume blinking. For normal text entry, this is OK. But when using the left and right arrow keys to move the cursor to edit a command, it's really annoying.

My Windows 7 machine doesn't have this issue; the cursor becomes visible when the arrow keys are tapped. How can I fix it in Vista?

Comment: Is this a repeatable problem when logging in as a different user?

Comment: I booted up my system today and it was gone. It should be repeatable, but I have no idea what triggers it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

osirisgothra was *almost* correct. I had the console's screen buffer height set to 3000; when it was full there was a tiny bit of redraw lag. Setting the buffer height to 500 resolved the issue.

Comment: I had the same Problem, but My cursor size was set to small and my buffer size was set to 3000. Setting the cursor size to Medium or Large and adjusting the buffer brought it back.

Answer (score 0):

I have had simmilar problem before, ended up being a spyware from who knows where, linking itself onto everything and affecting the performance. I believe that in all cmd consoles, the cursor disappears for a split millisecond, its just normally not noticeable to the human eye. You might want to get some sysinternals tools to check and make sure you dont have rogue dll or simmilar objects installed on the system bogging down the performance. Also, as it was a problem specific to vista (for me afaik) it might be fixable via a security update if MS has seen fit to make one for that problem. Vista was pretty slow in the first place -- and any little problem led to big delays even in the console, which is unacceptable...

Comment: Can't find any rouge DLLs. Also, I think I'd notice if the entire system was bogging down to the tune of half a second; it's just the console. Vista isn't _that_ slow; it's about as fast as Windows 7 since SP2.